# iOS: Prevent showing a specific notification when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using APNS for my app push notification service and I want to prevent showing a bunch of notifications with a specific title when app is in background.

I successfully did that when app is in foreground but I want to know how is it possible in background?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be sending two types of notification from your server. You should be sending normal notifications when you want the notification to display and you should be sending silent notifications when you don't want them to show, but want your app to use them for something.

More info on silent notifications [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently)